Theming container element w/ Angular Material
Wondering if its possible to theme an html element as a material container, in this case an error container. From material docs:

In that case setting the container theme, would also set the background color of the error container and the text color.

Any ideas if this is possible?
If its not possible I would assume its possibly to get the container and text colors for the error palette and set all of those individually for the container element.  I cannot find in the docs all the options for this.


please share the minimal reproducible code for checking, same problem in most of your question raised, there is nothing to debug, best if there is a stackblitz, where you tell you want it to work like this.

There are no material container / surface components in Angular Material AFAIK Though you can build your own. Checkout the guide about theming your own components for more info https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#step-2-use-values-from-the-theme You can see all SCSS APIs that Angular Material offers browsing the GitHub repository's index file https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/_index.scss You can learn there how things work under the hood to build upon that
